# How to use an AVG() and a JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, average

this is my SQL statement, but I cant get it to work. Could anyone perhaps tell me what I did wrong?

```
SELECT AVG(R.Rating), R.Track_id, T.Title, T.Artist, G.Genre, T.Track_length,    T.Track_release_date, A.Album, A.Album_release_date

FROM Track T, Genre G, Albums A
LEFT JOIN Rating ON Rating.Track_id = T.Track_id
WHERE G.Genre_id = T.Genre_id AND A.Album_id = T.Album_id AND T.Title = 'sometitle'
```

I perhaps should tell that I want to get the average ratings from 1 track. So if a title has a track id 25, it should look up every rating with track_id 25 and make an average of that selection.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or another RDBMS?

Comment: OleDb is what I am using atm

Comment: OLEDB isn't an RDBMS, it's an API used to connect to databases. Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

When using aggregate functions in a `SELECT` containing non-aggregated fields you need to group:

```
SELECT AVG(R.Rating), R.Track_id, T.Title, T.Artist, G.Genre, T.Track_length, 
    T.Track_release_date, A.Album, A.Album_release_date
FROM Track T, Genre G, Albums A
LEFT JOIN Rating R ON R.Track_id = T.Track_id
WHERE G.Genre_id = T.Genre_id 
    AND A.Album_id = T.Album_id 
    AND T.Title = 'sometitle'
GROUP BY R.Track_id, T.Title, T.Artist, G.Genre, T.Track_length, 
    T.Track_release_date, A.Album, A.Album_release_date
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177673.aspx) for more details.

You must `GROUP BY` all of the columns inside your `SELECT` that are not in an aggregate function.

Comment: "When using aggregate functions you need to group" - not necessarily; an aggregate function on an ungrouped dataset will return an aggregate result for the *whole* dataset - but it is what is required in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction, though I might see a problem which is still keeping me from using this query correctly. The R from R.Rating is not declared. How can this be fixed? (if its actually a problem that is)

Comment: @user1904252 I see that now. I have just fixed the query. The `Rating` table was missing an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a modern DBMS supporting window functions, the following should also do it

```
SELECT AVG(R.Rating) over (partition by r.track_id) as avg_rating, 
       R.Track_id, 
       T.Title, 
       T.Artist, 
       G.Genre, 
       T.Track_length, 
       T.Track_release_date, 
       A.Album, 
       A.Album_release_date
FROM Track T
JOIN Genre G ON G.Genre_id = T.Genre_id
JOIN Albums A ON A.Album_id = T.Album_id
LEFT JOIN Rating R ON R.Track_id = T.Track_id
WHERE T.Title = 'sometitle'
```